# Power BI query Connecting to API that uses HMAC Authentication

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am new to power bi, I need to connect to the web API using HMAC authentication. How I can send HMAC auth headers through web request?
Or How to do HMAC encryption in the PowerBi query

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Power BI Connector through that you can use Crypto.CreateHmac function and create HMAC auth headers

https://www.sqlgene.com/2019/02/19/create-a-power-query-custom-data-connector-in-10-minutes

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Crypto.createhmac has 3 arguments when using it in M/Power Connector, but the document in node.js only has two.

Comment: No didn't check for node.js

Answer (score 5):

It took me forever to realise that the following can be done and is a lot of out of the box thinking.

Create a function that generates a html document and have power query's built in rudimentary web browser execute JavaScript snippetes.
If your JS code references packages, you need to load them or create links to  CDN and change all double quotes to single quotes (I did in text edit with find/replace then copy/paste in code below between double quotes)

The following code will do HMAC-SHA512 with secret key (2 args).
New Blank Query and paste below code.
It took me 2 years since I first tried to do it until it clicked.
You're welcome!!!

```
(secret as text, payload as text) =>

let
    Source = Web.Page(
            "
    <script>
    //the following are CDN's from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js    and all double quotes replaced with single quotes
    //core    
    !function(t,n){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=n():'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],n):t.CryptoJS=n()}(this,function(){return function(f){var i;if('undefined'!=typeof window&&window.crypto&&(i=window.crypto),'undefined'!=typeof self&&self.crypto&&(i=self.crypto),!(i=!(i=!(i='undefined'!=typeof globalThis&&globalThis.crypto?globalThis.crypto:i)&&'undefined'!=typeof window&&window.msCrypto?window.msCrypto:i)&&'undefined'!=typeof global&&global.crypto?global.crypto:i)&&'function'==typeof require)try{i=require('crypto')}catch(t){}var e=Object.create||function(t){return n.prototype=t,t=new n,n.prototype=null,t};function n(){}var t={},r=t.lib={},o=r.Base={extend:function(t){var n=e(this);return t&&n.mixIn(t),n.hasOwnProperty('init')&&this.init!==n.init||(n.init=function(){n.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)}),(n.init.prototype=n).$super=this,n},create:function(){var t=this.extend();return t.init.apply(t,arguments),t},init:function(){},mixIn:function(t){for(var n in t)t.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(this[n]=t[n]);t.hasOwnProperty('toString')&&(this.toString=t.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}},u=r.WordArray=o.extend({init:function(t,n){t=this.words=t||[],this.sigBytes=null!=n?n:4*t.length},toString:function(t){return(t||a).stringify(this)},concat:function(t){var n=this.words,e=t.words,i=this.sigBytes,r=t.sigBytes;if(this.clamp(),i%4)for(var o=0;o<r;o++){var s=e[o>>>2]>>>24-o%4*8&255;n[i+o>>>2]|=s<<24-(i+o)%4*8}else for(var a=0;a<r;a+=4)n[i+a>>>2]=e[a>>>2];return this.sigBytes+=r,this},clamp:function(){var t=this.words,n=this.sigBytes;t[n>>>2]&=4294967295<<32-n%4*8,t.length=f.ceil(n/4)},clone:function(){var t=o.clone.call(this);return t.words=this.words.slice(0),t},random:function(t){for(var n=[],e=0;e<t;e+=4)n.push(function(){if(i){if('function'==typeof i.getRandomValues)try{return i.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]}catch(t){}if('function'==typeof i.randomBytes)try{return i.randomBytes(4).readInt32LE()}catch(t){}}throw new Error('Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number.')}());return new u.init(n,t)}}),s=t.enc={},a=s.Hex={stringify:function(t){for(var n=t.words,e=t.sigBytes,i=[],r=0;r<e;r++){var o=n[r>>>2]>>>24-r%4*8&255;i.push((o>>>4).toString(16)),i.push((15&o).toString(16))}return i.join('')},parse:function(t){for(var n=t.length,e=[],i=0;i<n;i+=2)e[i>>>3]|=parseInt(t.substr(i,2),16)<<24-i%8*4;return new u.init(e,n/2)}},c=s.Latin1={stringify:function(t){for(var n=t.words,e=t.sigBytes,i=[],r=0;r<e;r++){var o=n[r>>>2]>>>24-r%4*8&255;i.push(String.fromCharCode(o))}return i.join('')},parse:function(t){for(var n=t.length,e=[],i=0;i<n;i++)e[i>>>2]|=(255&t.charCodeAt(i))<<24-i%4*8;return new u.init(e,n)}},p=s.Utf8={stringify:function(t){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(c.stringify(t)))}catch(t){throw new Error('Malformed UTF-8 data')}},parse:function(t){return c.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(t)))}},d=r.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=o.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new u.init,this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(t){'string'==typeof t&&(t=p.parse(t)),this._data.concat(t),this._nDataBytes+=t.sigBytes},_process:function(t){var n,e=this._data,i=e.words,r=e.sigBytes,o=this.blockSize,s=r/(4*o),a=(s=t?f.ceil(s):f.max((0|s)-this._minBufferSize,0))*o,r=f.min(4*a,r);if(a){for(var c=0;c<a;c+=o)this._doProcessBlock(i,c);n=i.splice(0,a),e.sigBytes-=r}return new u.init(n,r)},clone:function(){var t=o.clone.call(this);return t._data=this._data.clone(),t},_minBufferSize:0}),h=(r.Hasher=d.extend({cfg:o.extend(),init:function(t){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(t),this.reset()},reset:function(){d.reset.call(this),this._doReset()},update:function(t){return this._append(t),this._process(),this},finalize:function(t){return t&&this._append(t),this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(e){return function(t,n){return new e.init(n).finalize(t)}},_createHmacHelper:function(e){return function(t,n){return new h.HMAC.init(e,n).finalize(t)}}}),t.algo={});return t}(Math)});

    //x64-core
    !function(t,e){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=e(require('./core')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core'],e):e(t.CryptoJS)}(this,function(t){var e,o,n,i;return o=(e=t).lib,n=o.Base,i=o.WordArray,(e=e.x64={}).Word=n.extend({init:function(t,e){this.high=t,this.low=e}}),e.WordArray=n.extend({init:function(t,e){t=this.words=t||[],this.sigBytes=null!=e?e:8*t.length},toX32:function(){for(var t=this.words,e=t.length,o=[],r=0;r<e;r++){var n=t[r];o.push(n.high),o.push(n.low)}return i.create(o,this.sigBytes)},clone:function(){for(var t=n.clone.call(this),e=t.words=this.words.slice(0),o=e.length,r=0;r<o;r++)e[r]=e[r].clone();return t}}),t});

    //sha512
    !function(i,h){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=h(require('./core'),require('./x64-core')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core','./x64-core'],h):h(i.CryptoJS)}(this,function(r){return function(){var i=r,h=i.lib.Hasher,o=i.x64,e=o.Word,n=o.WordArray,o=i.algo;function t(){return e.create.apply(e,arguments)}var i1=[t(1116352408,3609767458),t(1899447441,602891725),t(3049323471,3964484399),t(3921009573,2173295548),t(961987163,4081628472),t(1508970993,3053834265),t(2453635748,2937671579),t(2870763221,3664609560),t(3624381080,2734883394),t(310598401,1164996542),t(607225278,1323610764),t(1426881987,3590304994),t(1925078388,4068182383),t(2162078206,991336113),t(2614888103,633803317),t(3248222580,3479774868),t(3835390401,2666613458),t(4022224774,944711139),t(264347078,2341262773),t(604807628,2007800933),t(770255983,1495990901),t(1249150122,1856431235),t(1555081692,3175218132),t(1996064986,2198950837),t(2554220882,3999719339),t(2821834349,766784016),t(2952996808,2566594879),t(3210313671,3203337956),t(3336571891,1034457026),t(3584528711,2466948901),t(113926993,3758326383),t(338241895,168717936),t(666307205,1188179964),t(773529912,1546045734),t(1294757372,1522805485),t(1396182291,2643833823),t(1695183700,2343527390),t(1986661051,1014477480),t(2177026350,1206759142),t(2456956037,344077627),t(2730485921,1290863460),t(2820302411,3158454273),t(3259730800,3505952657),t(3345764771,106217008),t(3516065817,3606008344),t(3600352804,1432725776),t(4094571909,1467031594),t(275423344,851169720),t(430227734,3100823752),t(506948616,1363258195),t(659060556,3750685593),t(883997877,3785050280),t(958139571,3318307427),t(1322822218,3812723403),t(1537002063,2003034995),t(1747873779,3602036899),t(1955562222,1575990012),t(2024104815,1125592928),t(2227730452,2716904306),t(2361852424,442776044),t(2428436474,593698344),t(2756734187,3733110249),t(3204031479,2999351573),t(3329325298,3815920427),t(3391569614,3928383900),t(3515267271,566280711),t(3940187606,3454069534),t(4118630271,4000239992),t(116418474,1914138554),t(174292421,2731055270),t(289380356,3203993006),t(460393269,320620315),t(685471733,587496836),t(852142971,1086792851),t(1017036298,365543100),t(1126000580,2618297676),t(1288033470,3409855158),t(1501505948,4234509866),t(1607167915,987167468),t(1816402316,1246189591)],h1=[];!function(){for(var i=0;i<80;i++)h1[i]=t()}();o=o.SHA512=h.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new n.init([new e.init(1779033703,4089235720),new e.init(3144134277,2227873595),new e.init(1013904242,4271175723),new e.init(2773480762,1595750129),new e.init(1359893119,2917565137),new e.init(2600822924,725511199),new e.init(528734635,4215389547),new e.init(1541459225,327033209)])},_doProcessBlock:function(i,h){for(var o=this._hash.words,e=o[0],n=o[1],t=o[2],r=o[3],l=o[4],w=o[5],a=o[6],s=o[7],c=e.high,g=e.low,f=n.high,u=n.low,d=t.high,_=t.low,p=r.high,H=r.low,v=l.high,y=l.low,x=w.high,S=w.low,A=a.high,m=a.low,B=s.high,o=s.low,b=c,k=g,q=f,z=u,W=d,j=_,C=p,D=H,F=v,J=y,M=x,P=S,R=A,X=m,E=B,G=o,I=0;I<80;I++){var K,L,N=h1[I];I<16?(L=N.high=0|i[h+2*I],K=N.low=0|i[h+2*I+1]):($=(O=h1[I-15]).high,V=O.low,U=(Y=h1[I-2]).high,T=Y.low,Q=(Z=h1[I-7]).high,O=Z.low,Z=(Y=h1[I-16]).high,L=(L=(($>>>1|V<<31)^($>>>8|V<<24)^$>>>7)+Q+((K=(Q=(V>>>1|$<<31)^(V>>>8|$<<24)^(V>>>7|$<<25))+O)>>>0<Q>>>0?1:0))+((U>>>19|T<<13)^(U<<3|T>>>29)^U>>>6)+((K+=V=(T>>>19|U<<13)^(T<<3|U>>>29)^(T>>>6|U<<26))>>>0<V>>>0?1:0),K+=$=Y.low,N.high=L=L+Z+(K>>>0<$>>>0?1:0),N.low=K);var O=F&M^~F&R,Q=J&P^~J&X,T=b&q^b&W^q&W,U=(k>>>28|b<<4)^(k<<30|b>>>2)^(k<<25|b>>>7),V=i1[I],Y=V.high,Z=V.low,$=G+((J>>>14|F<<18)^(J>>>18|F<<14)^(J<<23|F>>>9)),N=E+((F>>>14|J<<18)^(F>>>18|J<<14)^(F<<23|J>>>9))+($>>>0<G>>>0?1:0),V=U+(k&z^k&j^z&j),E=R,G=X,R=M,X=P,M=F,P=J,F=C+(N=(N=(N=N+O+(($=$+Q)>>>0<Q>>>0?1:0))+Y+(($=$+Z)>>>0<Z>>>0?1:0))+L+(($=$+K)>>>0<K>>>0?1:0))+((J=D+$|0)>>>0<D>>>0?1:0)|0,C=W,D=j,W=q,j=z,q=b,z=k,b=N+(((b>>>28|k<<4)^(b<<30|k>>>2)^(b<<25|k>>>7))+T+(V>>>0<U>>>0?1:0))+((k=$+V|0)>>>0<$>>>0?1:0)|0}g=e.low=g+k,e.high=c+b+(g>>>0<k>>>0?1:0),u=n.low=u+z,n.high=f+q+(u>>>0<z>>>0?1:0),_=t.low=_+j,t.high=d+W+(_>>>0<j>>>0?1:0),H=r.low=H+D,r.high=p+C+(H>>>0<D>>>0?1:0),y=l.low=y+J,l.high=v+F+(y>>>0<J>>>0?1:0),S=w.low=S+P,w.high=x+M+(S>>>0<P>>>0?1:0),m=a.low=m+X,a.high=A+R+(m>>>0<X>>>0?1:0),o=s.low=o+G,s.high=B+E+(o>>>0<G>>>0?1:0)},_doFinalize:function(){var i=this._data,h=i.words,o=8*this._nDataBytes,e=8*i.sigBytes;return h[e>>>5]|=128<<24-e%32,h[30+(128+e>>>10<<5)]=Math.floor(o/4294967296),h[31+(128+e>>>10<<5)]=o,i.sigBytes=4*h.length,this._process(),this._hash.toX32()},clone:function(){var i=h.clone.call(this);return i._hash=this._hash.clone(),i},blockSize:32});i.SHA512=h._createHelper(o),i.HmacSHA512=h._createHmacHelper(o)}(),r.SHA512});

    //hmac
    !function(e,t){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=t(require('./core')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core'],t):t(e.CryptoJS)}(this,function(e){var t,a;t=e.lib.Base,a=e.enc.Utf8,e.algo.HMAC=t.extend({init:function(e,t){e=this._hasher=new e.init,'string'==typeof t&&(t=a.parse(t));var i=e.blockSize,n=4*i;(t=t.sigBytes>n?e.finalize(t):t).clamp();for(var e=this._oKey=t.clone(),t=this._iKey=t.clone(),s=e.words,r=t.words,o=0;o<i;o++)s[o]^=1549556828,r[o]^=909522486;e.sigBytes=t.sigBytes=n,this.reset()},reset:function(){var e=this._hasher;e.reset(),e.update(this._iKey)},update:function(e){return this._hasher.update(e),this},finalize:function(e){var t=this._hasher,e=t.finalize(e);return t.reset(),t.finalize(this._oKey.clone().concat(e))}})});


    !function(e,r){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=r(require('./core'),require('./x64-core'),require('./sha512'),require('./hmac')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core','./x64-core','./sha512','./hmac'],r):r(e.CryptoJS)}(this,function(e){return e.HmacSHA512});
    </script>
        
    <script>
        z= CryptoJS.HmacSHA512( """&payload&""", """&secret&""" );
        document.write(z);
    </script>

            "),
        Data = Source{0}[Data],
        Children = Data{0}[Children],
        Children1 = Children{1}[Children],
        Text = Children1{0}[Text]
in
    Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have collected data for clients using oAuth2 API. You can connect to any API using Power/M Query. Following is the sample code for my case, where in the first part I have collected the access_token and in second step, I have collected data using that access token. hope this will give you some idea on connecting to any API using Power Query.

```
let
    url = "your_authentication_url_here",

    body  = "{ ""client_id"": ""****"",  ""client_secret"": ""****"", ""grant_type"": ""****"", ""audience"":""****""}",
    tokenResponse = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,[Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json"], Content = Text.ToBinary(body) ] )),
    AccessToken = tokenResponse[access_token],
    AccessTokenHeader = "Bearer " & AccessToken,


    data_url = "your_main_url_here",
    data_body = "{
                    ""authorization"": """& AccessTokenHeader & """,
                    ""content-type"": ""application/json""
                }",

    GetGroups = Json.Document(
        Web.Contents(
            data_url, 
            [
                Headers = Json.Document(data_body)
            ] 
        )
    ),    

    categories = GetGroups[categories], --Category here will be changed as per your retrned data

    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(categories, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn
    (
        #"Converted to Table", "Column1", 
        {"ext_id", "shared", "report", "query", "_id", "description"}, --This is column returned from your data set
        {"ext_id", "shared", "report", "query", "_id", "description"}  -- Rename columns accordingly
    )
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```