# HMAC SHA256 function for PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

For an API I need a SHA256 method of authentication. In Base64.
My parameters are a secret and a string based on timestamp and user.

In order to get this working, the following code is a nice way to start:

[Power BI query Connecting to API that uses HMAC Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758873/power-bi-query-connecting-to-api-that-uses-hmac-authentication)

The problem is that this is in SHA512. And doesn’t have the conversion to Base64. This last part is properbly the easy part.

So is there anyone who can help us with a similar code as the above link, but then in sha256?

Example:
This Payload
09-05-2014|11:40:05.126|8700
Together with this secret
37d9ba90-2abf-4399-8dcc-e66fefed36d1

Should return in 256 Hex
8981828f590c69ed1fa6b5b14b21171b3d1697c3d42b18cfb4c9adf6f6720bce
And in SHA256 Base64
iYGCj1kMae0fprWxSyEXGz0Wl8PUKxjPtMmt9vZyC84=

EDIT after the response:

I changed it a little bit, my output is now Hex: 8981828f590c69ed1fa6b5b14b21171b3d1697c3d42b18cfb4c9adf6f6720bce

With other converters I can see this should be able to turn into the desired iYGCj1kMae0fprWxSyEXGz0Wl8PUKxjPtMmt9vZyC84=

But still not able to fix it in Power query. I saw this link

[HEX to Base64 converter for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190056/hex-to-base64-converter-for-javascript)

and tried to implement the function in js myself. But unfortunately my experience from 2 hours reading and trying js is just to little to get this working  Any help is welcome. Maybe even outside js, just in PQ

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added some more in the question. I hope you will have a look on the addition text. @DavideBacci

Comment: Where are you seeing that Base64 conversion? This site gives the code in my answer so where does yours come from? https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: Please mark as solved and/or upvote if the solution helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. According to this [site](https://www.base64encode.org/), the Base64 returns this which is the same as PQ:

> ODk4MTgyOGY1OTBjNjllZDFmYTZiNWIxNGIyMTE3MWIzZDE2OTdjM2Q0MmIxOGNmYjRjOWFkZjZmNjcyMGJjZQ==

```
(payload as text, secret as text) =>

let
    Source = Web.Page(
            "
    <script>
    //the following are CDN's from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js    and all double quotes replaced with single quotes
    //core    
    !function(t,n){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=n():'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],n):t.CryptoJS=n()}(this,function(){return function(f){var i;if('undefined'!=typeof window&&window.crypto&&(i=window.crypto),'undefined'!=typeof self&&self.crypto&&(i=self.crypto),!(i=!(i=!(i='undefined'!=typeof globalThis&&globalThis.crypto?globalThis.crypto:i)&&'undefined'!=typeof window&&window.msCrypto?window.msCrypto:i)&&'undefined'!=typeof global&&global.crypto?global.crypto:i)&&'function'==typeof require)try{i=require('crypto')}catch(t){}var e=Object.create||function(t){return n.prototype=t,t=new n,n.prototype=null,t};function n(){}var t={},r=t.lib={},o=r.Base={extend:function(t){var n=e(this);return t&&n.mixIn(t),n.hasOwnProperty('init')&&this.init!==n.init||(n.init=function(){n.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)}),(n.init.prototype=n).$super=this,n},create:function(){var t=this.extend();return t.init.apply(t,arguments),t},init:function(){},mixIn:function(t){for(var n in t)t.hasOwnProperty(n)&&(this[n]=t[n]);t.hasOwnProperty('toString')&&(this.toString=t.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}},u=r.WordArray=o.extend({init:function(t,n){t=this.words=t||[],this.sigBytes=null!=n?n:4*t.length},toString:function(t){return(t||a).stringify(this)},concat:function(t){var n=this.words,e=t.words,i=this.sigBytes,r=t.sigBytes;if(this.clamp(),i%4)for(var o=0;o<r;o++){var s=e[o>>>2]>>>24-o%4*8&255;n[i+o>>>2]|=s<<24-(i+o)%4*8}else for(var a=0;a<r;a+=4)n[i+a>>>2]=e[a>>>2];return this.sigBytes+=r,this},clamp:function(){var t=this.words,n=this.sigBytes;t[n>>>2]&=4294967295<<32-n%4*8,t.length=f.ceil(n/4)},clone:function(){var t=o.clone.call(this);return t.words=this.words.slice(0),t},random:function(t){for(var n=[],e=0;e<t;e+=4)n.push(function(){if(i){if('function'==typeof i.getRandomValues)try{return i.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]}catch(t){}if('function'==typeof i.randomBytes)try{return i.randomBytes(4).readInt32LE()}catch(t){}}throw new Error('Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number.')}());return new u.init(n,t)}}),s=t.enc={},a=s.Hex={stringify:function(t){for(var n=t.words,e=t.sigBytes,i=[],r=0;r<e;r++){var o=n[r>>>2]>>>24-r%4*8&255;i.push((o>>>4).toString(16)),i.push((15&o).toString(16))}return i.join('')},parse:function(t){for(var n=t.length,e=[],i=0;i<n;i+=2)e[i>>>3]|=parseInt(t.substr(i,2),16)<<24-i%8*4;return new u.init(e,n/2)}},c=s.Latin1={stringify:function(t){for(var n=t.words,e=t.sigBytes,i=[],r=0;r<e;r++){var o=n[r>>>2]>>>24-r%4*8&255;i.push(String.fromCharCode(o))}return i.join('')},parse:function(t){for(var n=t.length,e=[],i=0;i<n;i++)e[i>>>2]|=(255&t.charCodeAt(i))<<24-i%4*8;return new u.init(e,n)}},p=s.Utf8={stringify:function(t){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(c.stringify(t)))}catch(t){throw new Error('Malformed UTF-8 data')}},parse:function(t){return c.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(t)))}},d=r.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=o.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new u.init,this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(t){'string'==typeof t&&(t=p.parse(t)),this._data.concat(t),this._nDataBytes+=t.sigBytes},_process:function(t){var n,e=this._data,i=e.words,r=e.sigBytes,o=this.blockSize,s=r/(4*o),a=(s=t?f.ceil(s):f.max((0|s)-this._minBufferSize,0))*o,r=f.min(4*a,r);if(a){for(var c=0;c<a;c+=o)this._doProcessBlock(i,c);n=i.splice(0,a),e.sigBytes-=r}return new u.init(n,r)},clone:function(){var t=o.clone.call(this);return t._data=this._data.clone(),t},_minBufferSize:0}),h=(r.Hasher=d.extend({cfg:o.extend(),init:function(t){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(t),this.reset()},reset:function(){d.reset.call(this),this._doReset()},update:function(t){return this._append(t),this._process(),this},finalize:function(t){return t&&this._append(t),this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(e){return function(t,n){return new e.init(n).finalize(t)}},_createHmacHelper:function(e){return function(t,n){return new h.HMAC.init(e,n).finalize(t)}}}),t.algo={});return t}(Math)});

    //x64-core
    !function(t,e){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=e(require('./core')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core'],e):e(t.CryptoJS)}(this,function(t){var e,o,n,i;return o=(e=t).lib,n=o.Base,i=o.WordArray,(e=e.x64={}).Word=n.extend({init:function(t,e){this.high=t,this.low=e}}),e.WordArray=n.extend({init:function(t,e){t=this.words=t||[],this.sigBytes=null!=e?e:8*t.length},toX32:function(){for(var t=this.words,e=t.length,o=[],r=0;r<e;r++){var n=t[r];o.push(n.high),o.push(n.low)}return i.create(o,this.sigBytes)},clone:function(){for(var t=n.clone.call(this),e=t.words=this.words.slice(0),o=e.length,r=0;r<o;r++)e[r]=e[r].clone();return t}}),t});

    //sha512
    !function(i,h){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=h(require('./core'),require('./x64-core')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core','./x64-core'],h):h(i.CryptoJS)}(this,function(r){return function(){var i=r,h=i.lib.Hasher,o=i.x64,e=o.Word,n=o.WordArray,o=i.algo;function t(){return e.create.apply(e,arguments)}var i1=[t(1116352408,3609767458),t(1899447441,602891725),t(3049323471,3964484399),t(3921009573,2173295548),t(961987163,4081628472),t(1508970993,3053834265),t(2453635748,2937671579),t(2870763221,3664609560),t(3624381080,2734883394),t(310598401,1164996542),t(607225278,1323610764),t(1426881987,3590304994),t(1925078388,4068182383),t(2162078206,991336113),t(2614888103,633803317),t(3248222580,3479774868),t(3835390401,2666613458),t(4022224774,944711139),t(264347078,2341262773),t(604807628,2007800933),t(770255983,1495990901),t(1249150122,1856431235),t(1555081692,3175218132),t(1996064986,2198950837),t(2554220882,3999719339),t(2821834349,766784016),t(2952996808,2566594879),t(3210313671,3203337956),t(3336571891,1034457026),t(3584528711,2466948901),t(113926993,3758326383),t(338241895,168717936),t(666307205,1188179964),t(773529912,1546045734),t(1294757372,1522805485),t(1396182291,2643833823),t(1695183700,2343527390),t(1986661051,1014477480),t(2177026350,1206759142),t(2456956037,344077627),t(2730485921,1290863460),t(2820302411,3158454273),t(3259730800,3505952657),t(3345764771,106217008),t(3516065817,3606008344),t(3600352804,1432725776),t(4094571909,1467031594),t(275423344,851169720),t(430227734,3100823752),t(506948616,1363258195),t(659060556,3750685593),t(883997877,3785050280),t(958139571,3318307427),t(1322822218,3812723403),t(1537002063,2003034995),t(1747873779,3602036899),t(1955562222,1575990012),t(2024104815,1125592928),t(2227730452,2716904306),t(2361852424,442776044),t(2428436474,593698344),t(2756734187,3733110249),t(3204031479,2999351573),t(3329325298,3815920427),t(3391569614,3928383900),t(3515267271,566280711),t(3940187606,3454069534),t(4118630271,4000239992),t(116418474,1914138554),t(174292421,2731055270),t(289380356,3203993006),t(460393269,320620315),t(685471733,587496836),t(852142971,1086792851),t(1017036298,365543100),t(1126000580,2618297676),t(1288033470,3409855158),t(1501505948,4234509866),t(1607167915,987167468),t(1816402316,1246189591)],h1=[];!function(){for(var i=0;i<80;i++)h1[i]=t()}();o=o.SHA512=h.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new n.init([new e.init(1779033703,4089235720),new e.init(3144134277,2227873595),new e.init(1013904242,4271175723),new e.init(2773480762,1595750129),new e.init(1359893119,2917565137),new e.init(2600822924,725511199),new e.init(528734635,4215389547),new e.init(1541459225,327033209)])},_doProcessBlock:function(i,h){for(var o=this._hash.words,e=o[0],n=o[1],t=o[2],r=o[3],l=o[4],w=o[5],a=o[6],s=o[7],c=e.high,g=e.low,f=n.high,u=n.low,d=t.high,_=t.low,p=r.high,H=r.low,v=l.high,y=l.low,x=w.high,S=w.low,A=a.high,m=a.low,B=s.high,o=s.low,b=c,k=g,q=f,z=u,W=d,j=_,C=p,D=H,F=v,J=y,M=x,P=S,R=A,X=m,E=B,G=o,I=0;I<80;I++){var K,L,N=h1[I];I<16?(L=N.high=0|i[h+2*I],K=N.low=0|i[h+2*I+1]):($=(O=h1[I-15]).high,V=O.low,U=(Y=h1[I-2]).high,T=Y.low,Q=(Z=h1[I-7]).high,O=Z.low,Z=(Y=h1[I-16]).high,L=(L=(($>>>1|V<<31)^($>>>8|V<<24)^$>>>7)+Q+((K=(Q=(V>>>1|$<<31)^(V>>>8|$<<24)^(V>>>7|$<<25))+O)>>>0<Q>>>0?1:0))+((U>>>19|T<<13)^(U<<3|T>>>29)^U>>>6)+((K+=V=(T>>>19|U<<13)^(T<<3|U>>>29)^(T>>>6|U<<26))>>>0<V>>>0?1:0),K+=$=Y.low,N.high=L=L+Z+(K>>>0<$>>>0?1:0),N.low=K);var O=F&M^~F&R,Q=J&P^~J&X,T=b&q^b&W^q&W,U=(k>>>28|b<<4)^(k<<30|b>>>2)^(k<<25|b>>>7),V=i1[I],Y=V.high,Z=V.low,$=G+((J>>>14|F<<18)^(J>>>18|F<<14)^(J<<23|F>>>9)),N=E+((F>>>14|J<<18)^(F>>>18|J<<14)^(F<<23|J>>>9))+($>>>0<G>>>0?1:0),V=U+(k&z^k&j^z&j),E=R,G=X,R=M,X=P,M=F,P=J,F=C+(N=(N=(N=N+O+(($=$+Q)>>>0<Q>>>0?1:0))+Y+(($=$+Z)>>>0<Z>>>0?1:0))+L+(($=$+K)>>>0<K>>>0?1:0))+((J=D+$|0)>>>0<D>>>0?1:0)|0,C=W,D=j,W=q,j=z,q=b,z=k,b=N+(((b>>>28|k<<4)^(b<<30|k>>>2)^(b<<25|k>>>7))+T+(V>>>0<U>>>0?1:0))+((k=$+V|0)>>>0<$>>>0?1:0)|0}g=e.low=g+k,e.high=c+b+(g>>>0<k>>>0?1:0),u=n.low=u+z,n.high=f+q+(u>>>0<z>>>0?1:0),_=t.low=_+j,t.high=d+W+(_>>>0<j>>>0?1:0),H=r.low=H+D,r.high=p+C+(H>>>0<D>>>0?1:0),y=l.low=y+J,l.high=v+F+(y>>>0<J>>>0?1:0),S=w.low=S+P,w.high=x+M+(S>>>0<P>>>0?1:0),m=a.low=m+X,a.high=A+R+(m>>>0<X>>>0?1:0),o=s.low=o+G,s.high=B+E+(o>>>0<G>>>0?1:0)},_doFinalize:function(){var i=this._data,h=i.words,o=8*this._nDataBytes,e=8*i.sigBytes;return h[e>>>5]|=128<<24-e%32,h[30+(128+e>>>10<<5)]=Math.floor(o/4294967296),h[31+(128+e>>>10<<5)]=o,i.sigBytes=4*h.length,this._process(),this._hash.toX32()},clone:function(){var i=h.clone.call(this);return i._hash=this._hash.clone(),i},blockSize:32});i.SHA512=h._createHelper(o),i.HmacSHA512=h._createHmacHelper(o)}(),r.SHA512});

    //sha256
    !function(e,r){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=r(require('./core')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core'],r):r(e.CryptoJS)}(this,function(e){var n=Math,r=e,t=(s=r.lib).WordArray,o=s.Hasher,s=r.algo,i=[],_=[];function a(e){return 4294967296*(e-(0|e))|0}for(var c=2,h=0;h<64;)!function(e){for(var r=n.sqrt(e),t=2;t<=r;t++)if(!(e%t))return;return 1}(c)||(h<8&&(i[h]=a(n.pow(c,.5))),_[h]=a(n.pow(c,1/3)),h++),c++;var p=[],s=s.SHA256=o.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new t.init(i.slice(0))},_doProcessBlock:function(e,r){for(var t=this._hash.words,o=t[0],n=t[1],s=t[2],i=t[3],a=t[4],c=t[5],h=t[6],f=t[7],u=0;u<64;u++){u<16?p[u]=0|e[r+u]:(l=p[u-15],d=p[u-2],p[u]=((l<<25|l>>>7)^(l<<14|l>>>18)^l>>>3)+p[u-7]+((d<<15|d>>>17)^(d<<13|d>>>19)^d>>>10)+p[u-16]);var l=o&n^o&s^n&s,d=f+((a<<26|a>>>6)^(a<<21|a>>>11)^(a<<7|a>>>25))+(a&c^~a&h)+_[u]+p[u],f=h,h=c,c=a,a=i+d|0,i=s,s=n,n=o,o=d+(((o<<30|o>>>2)^(o<<19|o>>>13)^(o<<10|o>>>22))+l)|0}t[0]=t[0]+o|0,t[1]=t[1]+n|0,t[2]=t[2]+s|0,t[3]=t[3]+i|0,t[4]=t[4]+a|0,t[5]=t[5]+c|0,t[6]=t[6]+h|0,t[7]=t[7]+f|0},_doFinalize:function(){var e=this._data,r=e.words,t=8*this._nDataBytes,o=8*e.sigBytes;return r[o>>>5]|=128<<24-o%32,r[14+(64+o>>>9<<4)]=n.floor(t/4294967296),r[15+(64+o>>>9<<4)]=t,e.sigBytes=4*r.length,this._process(),this._hash},clone:function(){var e=o.clone.call(this);return e._hash=this._hash.clone(),e}});return r.SHA256=o._createHelper(s),r.HmacSHA256=o._createHmacHelper(s),e.SHA256});

    //hmac
    !function(e,t){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=t(require('./core')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core'],t):t(e.CryptoJS)}(this,function(e){var t,a;t=e.lib.Base,a=e.enc.Utf8,e.algo.HMAC=t.extend({init:function(e,t){e=this._hasher=new e.init,'string'==typeof t&&(t=a.parse(t));var i=e.blockSize,n=4*i;(t=t.sigBytes>n?e.finalize(t):t).clamp();for(var e=this._oKey=t.clone(),t=this._iKey=t.clone(),s=e.words,r=t.words,o=0;o<i;o++)s[o]^=1549556828,r[o]^=909522486;e.sigBytes=t.sigBytes=n,this.reset()},reset:function(){var e=this._hasher;e.reset(),e.update(this._iKey)},update:function(e){return this._hasher.update(e),this},finalize:function(e){var t=this._hasher,e=t.finalize(e);return t.reset(),t.finalize(this._oKey.clone().concat(e))}})});


    !function(e,r){'object'==typeof exports?module.exports=exports=r(require('./core'),require('./x64-core'),require('./sha512'),require('./hmac')):'function'==typeof define&&define.amd?define(['./core','./x64-core','./sha512','./hmac'],r):r(e.CryptoJS)}(this,function(e){return e.HmacSHA512});
    </script>
        
    <script>
        z= CryptoJS.HmacSHA256( """&payload&""", """&secret&""" );
        document.write(z);
    </script>

            "),
        Data = Source{0}[Data],
        Children = Data{0}[Children],
        Children1 = Children{1}[Children],
        Text = Children1{0}[Text],
        Encode =  Binary.ToText( Text.ToBinary(Text, BinaryEncoding.Base64))
in
    Encode
```